# Excel - Creating a dynamic dropdown of values that match a string

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, reference, spreadsheet, vlookup

In excel I am trying to create a dropdown which pulls in all values where part of that value is in the cell next to the dropdown

So I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns, a description and a price.

I have another spreadsheet which will have the dropdown and in the cell to the left of the dropdown I will enter text. When entering text, I want the dropdown to find all values in the other spreadsheet where this text matches.

Finally once they click the dropdown it will take the price into the cell to the right.

First of all does anyone know if this is possible. If it is if you could give me just a little guidance in how to do it it would be much appreciated. I'm not expecting a fools guide just a nudge in the right direction and i'll work out the rest.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: What kind of Drop Down? Excel Data Validation List In-Cell Dropdown, Form Control List Box/Combo List/Combo Drop Down, Active X Combo Box/List Box?

Comment: A form control list box would probably be best if it is possible with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using vb code in the end.